# Merge Array of String - No exact matches in call to subscript

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, zip, subscript

I'm getting an Xcode error

> Global function 'zip' requires that 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') conform to 'Sequence'

on `array[i] = zip(array[i], arrayOfZeros)`

```
func expandedForm(_ num: Int) -> String {
  
    let lenght = String(num).count
    var array = Array(String(num))
    
    var i = 0
    while array.count > i {
        
        let numberOfZeros = array.count - 1 - i
        let arrayOfZeros = Array(repeating: "0", count: numberOfZeros)
        let string = array[i]
        array[i] = zip(array[i], arrayOfZeros)
        i += 1
    }
    
    return ""
}
```

I'm trying to merge two array of strings, but I think they are not the same type. Need some help on this.

Comment: `zip()` needs two sequences (~Swift Array, it's not exactly that, but let's keep it as this level of simplification). `array[i]` is a `Character`, so it's not an array. So you can't zip on it. What's your expected output? You want for `234`, `["200" , "30", "3"]`?

Comment: That's exactly what I want!

Comment: `array` is a `Array<Character>` (ie `[Character]`), so you can't put a `String` in it, like "200". Could you make it an array of `String`, with `var array = Array(String(num)).map { String($0) }`, or just create another variable: `var output: [String] = []`, and then do `output.append(String(array[i]) + + arrayOfZeros.joined())`

Comment: @Larme put that as an answer so I can check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func expandedForm(_ num: Int) -> String {
  
    let lenght = String(num).count
    var array = Array(String(num))
    
    var i = 0
    while array.count > i {
        
        let numberOfZeros = array.count - 1 - i
        let arrayOfZeros = Array(repeating: "0", count: numberOfZeros)
        let string = array[i]
        array[i] = zip(array[i], arrayOfZeros)
        i += 1
    }
    
    return ""
}
```

You have some issues.

`var array = Array(String(num))`, if you pass your cursor on `array`, it's a `[String.Element]`, ie a `[Character]`, an array a `Character`.

So `let string = array[i]`, that's misleading, because `array[i]` is a `Character`, not a `String`.

`zip(_:_:)` awaits for two sequences (~array), and you give as first parameter a `Character`.

Possible solutions:

Make `array`, a real array of `String`:

```
var array = Array(String(num)).map { String($0) }
```

And then:

```
array[i] = array[i] + arrayOfZeros.joined()
```

Or create a new variable `var output` that will be an array of `String`:

```
var output: [String] = []
```

And populate it:

```
output.append(String(array[i] + arrayOfZeros.joined())
```